# Literature on how to design a notification sound?

Tags: usability-testing, notification, usability-study, sound

A part of a thesis, I need to design a couple auditory notifications in a car. Something along the lines of "check tire pressure", which isn't a warning. I have written down some relatively vague guidelines on how to design a notification from few books and by analyzing existing ones for comparison. I can dissect them and for example say "I think the short melody should be in major key", but there's almost no literature on that. You can find a lot more on actual warnings.

Where can I find studies and maybe usability tests specifically on notifications? Thanks

Comment: Google Scholar search for "notification sound" might yield some useful results. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_vis=1&q=notification+sound&hl=en&as_sdt=1,5

Comment: Ah yes I completely forgot about this website. That's helpful

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the talk **Designing Sound** from Apple's developer conference WWDC 2019. A couple of minutes in, the speaker talks about notifications, including notifications that express success.

The talk is not an academic study of course but it is a nice summary of how Apple thinks about using sounds so I think you could use it as a source that brings a lot of weight.

Good luck!

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/803/

Comment: Very nice! Not 100% what i've been looking for but helpful nonetheless. I'm not sure how I can cite this in my thesis but I'll figure that out.